# How is the diagonal constraint in lattice path needed for the Catalan proofs?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics, catalan-numbers

I have been reading about the Catalan numbers and how they are they appear in many problems such as:

- lattice paths
- valid pair of parenthesis
- mountains with up/downstrokes
- non-crossing handshakes
- rooted plane bushes

The explanations I have seen on why all these problems have the same solution take a rather visual approach. For example:
Mountains vs parenthesis

```
/\ ()

 /\
/  \  (())  

/\/\/\ ()()()
```

those seem to make sense trying to show the balance between $2$ symmetric symbols.
When trying to show how we derive the Catalan number all examples I have seen base it on the first example i.e. lattice paths which is basically reduced to the problem of the number of paths going from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ moving only in upwards or to the right i.e. again $2$ symbols ($U$ and $R$) with the additional constraint that the path never goes bellow the diagonal.
I do understand that there is the similarity of having $2$ symbols again, also that we need to have a sequence of the same number of $U$ and $R$ as in the parenthesis and the mountains but I don't really understand how the diagonal constraint fits into all of this.
So taking a specific example i.e. moving from $(0,0)$ to $(3,3)$ we have a valid case bellow staying above the diagonal:
[image]

This is equivalent to $U \space R \space U \space R \space U \space R$
Another valid path is $U \space U \space R \space R \space U\space R$
[image]

The following violates the diagonal constraint

[image]

It is the path: $U \space R\space R\space R\space U \space U$
Again we have the same number of $U$ and $R$ but the condition path is violated.

My question is: How is the condition of the diagonal related with the problem of the valid pair of parenthesis? What changes exactly when we cross the diagonal that reduces the problem to be the same one as the rest?

Comment: Note that there are lots(!) of combinatorial interpretations of the Catalan numbers. See Catalan Addendum to Enumerative Combinatorics by Richard Stanley 
(https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/catadd.pdf) and this page https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/lectures/Cat/pakcat.htm (Igor Pak).

Comment: @richrow: Do we know how they figured the original idea for the proof? I think it existed before the mathematician Catalan formally introduced them?

Comment: I am not an expert in the field of history of mathematics and I don't know (but there is stackechange site for this topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`U` corresponds to `(`  and `R` corresponds to `)`.  If you cross the diagonal, then at the first point after you cross the diagonal, you have more R's than U's, so you have more `)` than `(` so the sequence can no longer be completed to a sequence of balanced parentheses.  For example, `URR` becomes `())` which is unbalanced.

Comment: How can I have move $R$ than $U$? When I reach $(3,3)$ I always have the same number of $R$ and $U$. Do you mean the first point after the diagonal?

Comment: Yes, the first point after the diagonal. Edited for clarity.

Comment: So even thought $U$ and $R$ by themselves do not start/end a path it is the mapping itself to $($ and $)$ that creates the imbalance? Because otherwise in the lattice paths specifically, the constraint to be above the diagonal seems arbitrary. Or in the lattice paths too there is something more to this constraint?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You are trying to get a condition on lattice paths that corresponds to balanced parentheses so you need to consider the map to parentheses to see what that condition is.

Comment: When we have the parenthesis, it is clear when they are not well formed. I was wondering if the diagonal had a similar meaning leaving the mapping to parenthesis aside. The only thing I could think of is that it represents the line of symmetry since the paths above and bellow the diagonal are symmetrical while any path that breaks the diagonal has no symmetrical equivalent